# How to put grommets in a tarp?

Tags: tools

If I have a custom sized tarp, is there any way for me to put a grommet where I need it, in a process similar to riveting for example?

Answer (score 3):

YES, purchase (then practice a bit) with a grommet setting tool kit. manufacturers use automated machines for it, but this is the original "old school" way it was done.

[image]

Comment: P.S. they come in different sizes, or there are kits with several tools and grommet sizes.